# How to add new terminal type after installation gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have installed gnuplot 5.0 using source code in my Ubuntu 14.04. Gnuplot is working but has not **wxt** and **png** terminal. Now I want to add this terminal.

output of `gnuplot>set terminal` results this-

```
Available terminal types:
       canvas  HTML Canvas object
          cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
      context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
        corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW
      domterm  DomTerm terminal emulator with embedded SVG
         dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
          dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
        eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment
          emf  Enhanced Metafile format
        emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials
     epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
          fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor
         hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
        latex  LaTeX picture environment
           mf  Metafont plotting standard
           mp  MetaPost plotting standard
         pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
   postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
      pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
        pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
     pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
          qms  QMS/QUIC Laser printer (also Talaris 1200 and others)
          svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics
      tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators
      tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals
      texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
         tgif  TGIF X11 [mode] [x,y] [dashed] ["font" [fontsize]]
     tkcanvas  Tk canvas widget
         tpic  TPIC -- LaTeX picture environment with tpic \specials
Press return for more: 
          unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
            vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator
            xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are the development packages for wxt and png installed?

Comment: @thrig no. Just I have downloaded these.

Answer (score 1):

To prepare for installing from source most of the required packages should be made available (in Ubuntu and Debian) by running `sudo apt build-dep <package>`. To make this work enable some deb-src ppa's in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `apt update`. For me it was sufficient to remove some comment markers. Be aware that there might be features in the package you want to build from source that require dependecies that are not available in the distributions ppa's.

Also some features are not enabled by default and can only be built if the package is configured to provide them. Often one can find out what flags must be used by running `cd /path/to/src/; ./configure --help`.

Comment: For instance right now I'm trying to enable the linux and svga terminals via compiling from source which is failing due to lack of `svgalib` in Ubuntus repos.

Comment: The linux/vgagl gnuplot terminals are effectively obsolete, since svgalib itself is not usable.  The current recommendation for using gnuplot from the linux console is to install a console terminal such as yaft that supports sixel graphics.  Then you can run gnuplot from the yaft console and select "set term sixel".   Gnuplot provides sixel output from two different terminals.  The most feature-full alternative is sixelgd, which is build automatically if you have installed the development packages for libgd.